# Run bash command from windows Command line (WSL)

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed WSL on Windows 10 Pro. 
And I need to execute bash commands from Windows Command Line like this:

```
bash -c ll
```

Expected: `ll` command output in Command Line console

In practice: `/bin/bash: ll: command not found`

But its work for some commands like `ls` or `apt`.

Please, see :

[image: screenshot with example]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ll` is a common alias (for `ls -alF` in WSL; defined in the default `.bashrc`).  Depending on how you invoke `bash` will determine whether the scripts which set up your system aliases are run.  See the `INVOCATION` section of the `bash` manual.

You can use `bash -i -c ll` to invoke `bash` in an appropriate way for WSL.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `ll` is an alias you defined in some of your configuration files. You should start bash as follows:

```
bash -ilc ll
```

Depending on where you defined the aliases, you can omit the `-i` or `-l` flag.

Answer (score 1):

`ll` is usually an alias of `'ls -l` and can't (shouldn't) be used in script or command line.

Instead use directly the command itself: `bash -c 'ls -l'`.

To see if a certain command is an alias use the command `type`:

```
type ll
ll is aliased to `ls -l'
```